# java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar

Tags: java, junit, jersey, jax-rs

im writing a JAX-RS API.

When trying to run the following unit-test:

```
    @Test
    public void verifyUserTest() throws InvalidTokenException, InvalidUserException {
        Mockito.when(service.verifyLogin(Mockito.any(LoginRequestDTO.class))).thenReturn(true);
        Mockito.when(service.createToken(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn("testToken");



        var res = sut.verifyUser(new LoginRequestDTO("testuser", "testpass"));
        var entity = res.getEntity();
        System.out.println(entity);

       // Assertions.assertEquals("testuser", res.getUsername());
      //  Assertions.assertEquals("testToken", res.getToken());

    }
```

I'm getting the following error:

`java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/javax/javaee-web-api/8.0.1/javaee-web-api-8.0.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class to jar:file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/javax/javaee-web-api/8.0.1/javaee-web-api-8.0.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class`

This looks (to me) like the same class is being loaded twice. How would i resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I have fixed this issue by changing dependencies in my pom.xml.

I had both

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This combination of dependencies caused the classcast error. Changing the version of the jersey-client dependency to "2.34" has fixed the issue.

Comment: I personnally fixed the issue by using the version 2.24 of all my org.glassfish.jersey dependencies