# How to fix LinkageError when running Wiremock tests with javax.ws.rs dependency after upgrading to Java 17?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am upgrading a project from Java 11 to Java 17 and in the process upgraded Wiremock to com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:3.0.0-beta-8 and spring boot to group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux', version: '3.0.6.

I am getting a LinkageError.

When I run the test cases (supported by WireMock) they fail with this error.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/Users/UserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1.1/d3466bc9321fe84f268a1adb3b90373fc14b0eb5/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class to jar:file:/Users/UserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1.1/d3466bc9321fe84f268a1adb3b90373fc14b0eb5/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:81)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:109)
    at com.appdynamics.eum.rest.client.JaxRsClient$Builder.build(JaxRsClient.java:128)
```

I have tried clearing the gradle cache and various things suggested here on Stackoverflow by people facing similar issues but not able to resolve it ([java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67419289/java-lang-linkageerror-classcastexception-attempting-to-castjar)).